# SQL - losing time part of datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have the following code which converts an nvarchar to a datetime.

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), LEFT([SubmitDate], 10), 103) AS DATETIME USING 'en-gb') AS [SubmitDate]
FROM [ITSM_INCIDENT]
```

When I do the conversion I lose the time part of the datetime

e.g.

'2017-01-01 13:23:01.000' goes to '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000'

How can I write this so the time doesn't all go to 0's?

Comment: `left(..., 10)` will take remove the time part from string. Perhaps use `left(col, 19)` or `left(col, 23)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `left()` to only grab the date part (first 10) of the variable.

Try using this instead:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), LEFT([SubmitDate], 23), 103) AS DATETIME USING 'en-gb') AS [SubmitDate]
FROM [ITSM_INCIDENT]
```